# From user input to list content

Tags: python, list

I recently started my first few python tutorials and came across something for which I cannot find an answer.

I created various lists containing different information.
For example a list of easy pancake ingredients.

```
pancakes = (eggs, milk, flour)
```

Now I want to access the ingredients through the user inputting "pancakes"

For example:

```
foods = input("type something") #I type in 'pancakes'

print(foods)
```

and then it would print the items stored in the list belonging to 'pancakes'

```
eggs, milk, flour
```

but this does not work... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to store the ingredients of each food (assuming that you will want to support more than one):

```
foods = {'pancakes': ('eggs', 'milk', 'flour')}
wanted = input('type something: ')
print(foods.get(wanted, 'You requested non-existing food'))
```

I used `.get` to handle the case the inputted food does not exist.

BTW, `('eggs', 'milk', 'flour')` is a tuple, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `pancakes` python treats it as a string (not a variable) and set the value of foods to the word pancakes (which explains that if you run this code it will output `pancakes`).

If you want to output the contents of the tuple when you type the word `pancakes` I would recommend doing the following:

```
pancakes = (eggs, milk, flour)
foods = input("type something") #I type in 'pancakes'

if foods == "pancakes":
    print(pancakes)
```

What happens in this code is that when you type `pancakes` the [if statement](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp) will check if the `foods` variable is equal to the word `pancakes`. If so it will then print the tuple `pancakes`.

---

In a more practical fashion I would recommend storing all the recipes in a dictionary so something like this:

```
recipes = {"pancakes" :["eggs", "milk", "flour")}

foods = input("type something") #I type in 'pancakes'

if foods in recipes.keys():
    print(recipes[foods])
else:
    print("recipe not found")
```

(what happens here is the script checks if the food that you typed is in `recipes` if so it prints the recipe. If it can't find it, it prints `recipe not found`)

Hope this helps

Comment: That is what I thought to do in the first place. But I wanted to find a nicer solution for it. If say besides pancakes there is also muffins, breadrolls etc. the number of if/ elif statements I have to write gets insane quickly

Answer (score 0):

To have ingredients for multiple recipes, you can use a dictionary:

```
recipes = {
  'pancakes': ('eggs', 'milk', 'flour')
  'omlettes': ('eggs', 'cheese', 'ham', 'onions')
}
```

Now when the recipe enters `'pancakes'`, you can get the tuple of ingredients directly from the dictionary:

```
foods = input("type something") #I type in 'pancakes'

print(recipes[foods])
```

Several points of clarification:

1. When you surround a sequence of items with `()`, you get a `tuple`, not a `list`. I suggest you do some research and learn about the differences between these two.
2. Note how I surround each ingredient with `''`. This means that each word is a *string*.
3. Similarly, `'pancakes'` is a string when you type it as input. This string can be used as the key to the dictionary `ingredients` to look up the ingredients.